# Flutter: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception, execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseJavaResource'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

flutter build apk is not working due to this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> invalid stream header: 00000000

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

adroid/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        disable "Instantiatable"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mobilemaster.foodbazarapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
}
```

flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.1.0-9.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1586], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.1.0-9.0.pre at C:\src\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision f28e570c8c (9 days ago), 2022-06-14 13:39:33 -0500
• Engine revision 74ee6b5afd
• Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-165.1.beta)
• DevTools version 2.14.0

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\OSAMA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 33.0.0-rc2
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.6)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.0.32126.317
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
• IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2
• Flutter plugin version 65.2.1
• Dart plugin version 203.8452

[√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
• VS Code at C:\Users\OSAMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.68.1)
• VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
• sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
• Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1586]
• Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.53
• Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.44

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

Comment: Can you provide flutter doctor -v and complete flutter run -v in properly formatted text ?